# read remote properties file over ssh oozie

Tags: hadoop, ssh, oozie

I want to run oozie workflow from remote machine whereas my config file exists on local machine. could you please help me how I can achieve this?

I tried below approach but it didnt work:

```
ssh user@remote_host "oozie job -run -config" < config.properties
```

giving error

```
Invalid sub-command: Missing argument for option: config

use 'help [sub-command]' for help details
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass properties in you config file with `-D`, such as:

```
ssh user@remote_host "oozie job -run -D oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://hdf-example-cluster -D key=value"
```

Oozie will read specific value from system properties if you don't provide.

Comment: Thank you. But I have too many parameters with me and it is difficult to place key value pairs using -D option. Do you have any other alternative?